# how to createElement with an id in one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i know that i can create an element such as:

```
var foo = document.createElement('div');
```

and to set the div id i would do as such:

```
foo.setAttribute('id', 'divName');
```

and if you google long enough you will find someone doing code such as here

```
var google = createElement("a",{"href":"http://google.com"},"google"),
    youtube = createElement("a",{"href":"http://youtube.com"},"youtube"),
    facebook = createElement("a",{"href":"http://facebook.com"},"facebook"),
    links_conteiner = createElement("div",{"id":"links"},[google,youtube,facebook]);
```

which would equal out to:

```
var foo = document.createElement('div', {'id':'divName);
```

yet when i run the above code the `id` or `divName` is not added and instead an empty div is created. so i am curious what i am doing wrong, and if it is even possible to both create and set the div name for an element using `.createElement` only?

Comment: you have a syntax error on `var foo = document.createElement('div', {'id':'divName);` should be `var foo = document.createElement('div', {'id':'divName'});`. was it a typo?

Comment: is the quiestion is using jQuery also?? `$('<div id="some_id">')` ?

Comment: Well there is a method there that does it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    var createElement = function (tagName, id, attrs, events) {
      attrs = Object.assign(attrs || {}, { id: id });
      events = Object.assign(events || {});
      
      var el = document.createElement(tagName);
      Object.keys(attrs).forEach((key) => {
        if (attrs [key] !== undefined) {
          el.setAttribute(key, attrs [key]);
        }
      });
      
      Object.keys(events).forEach((key) => {
        if (typeof events [key] === 'function') {
          el.addEventListener(key, events [key]);
        }
      });

      return el;
    }

    createElement('div');
```

Answer (score 23):

If you want to add an object in one line, you can use:

```
Object.assign(document.createElement('div'),{id:"fd"})
```

here it is in action:

```js
document.body.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('div'),{textContent:"fd"}));
```

no jquery needed.

Comment: Object.assign(document.createElement('div'),{id:"fd"})

Comment: $ = (el,attrs) => Object.assign(document.createElement(el),attrs);  document.body.appendchild($("div",{id:"id"}));

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can create your own prototype which will do it for you. Not the best solution, but will make you able to create element in one line and add attributes to it:

```
document.__proto__.customCreateElement = function(tag, attributes){
    var e = document.createElement(tag);

    for(var a in attributes) e.setAttribute(a, attributes[a]);

    return e;
}
```

And then:

```
var a = document.customCreateElement('div', {id: "myId", name: "myName"});
```

results in:

```
<div id="myId" name="myName"></div>
```

Of course if you want to make it in pure JavaScript without any frameworks or libraries.

Comment: if we are writing a function and calling it, instead we can write a normal function. what is the extra benefit to putting it in `document`?

Comment: Good point. I was just thinking about overriding `createElement` prototype but changed my mind and I left it like this

Answer (score 1):

According to the [spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-createelement) , `createElement` accepts a second `option` object which only can have the `is` attribute. Unfortunately nothing for id, class style.. See also the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: This one actually does not work. For me at least. When I print `foo` it is `undefined`

Comment: @Sebastian, yes you are right not the element was assigned to the foo

Comment: so sad that we have to create a new line just to assign a div declaration

Comment: This is the only response that actually explains why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery you can write according to the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes):

```
$('<div/>', {id: 'divName'})
```

```js
var ele = $('<div/>', {id: 'divName'});

console.log(ele.get(0).outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```